# Al comparar dos strings siempre me dan error(No son iguales) - Javascript - DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Tengo un problema, al comparar dos strings "*clickedColor*" y "*pickedColor*" siempre me aparece el fallo de que no son iguales y no consigo ver el porque.
Agradezco toda la ayuda posible.

Aqui el codepen: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/elvarox301/pen/GQPKeG)

**ColorRandomizer** genera tres valores aleatorios R G y B y los va metiendo a un Array de cuadrados (squares), luego el color asignado lo mete a un Array de Strings (squareColor).

**pickedColor** coge un valor aleatorio dentro del Array de squareColor y se asigna

**CreateClickEvents** es donde me da que siempre es falso, tras crear los eventos de click. En estos, si el background es igual a pickedColor deberia salir correcto, si no, error. La cosa es que SIEMPRE ME SALE ERROR

Aqui pego el codigo del archivo js

```
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var squareColor = [];

var colorToGuess = document.querySelector("#colorToGuess");
//Color variables
var R = 0;
var G = 0;
var B = 0;

//console.log(pickedColor);

colorRandomizer();
var pickedColor = squareColor[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)];
createClickEvents();
colorToGuess.textContent = pickedColor;

//Randomize boxes with colors and fill squareColor[]
function colorRandomizer () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= squares.length - 1; i++) {
        R = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        G = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        B = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb( " + R + ", " + G + ", " + B + ")";
        squareColor.push("rgb( " + R + ", " + G + ", " + B + ")");
        //console.log(squareColor[i]);
            }
}

function createClickEvents () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= squares.length - 1; i++) {
        squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
            if(clickedColor === pickedColor){
                alert("Correct!");
            }else{
                alert("Wrong!");
                this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
            } 
        })
    }


}
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: y que de que no son iguales, esta malo? digo.. verificas que lo que se genere aleatoriamente sea igual al background color que tienes? puedes agregarlo a algun JSFiddle o Codepen para ver el funcionamiento?

Comment: @sioesi La cosa es que minimo uno tiene que estar bien, en 2 minutos subo un codepen

Comment: gracias!, intentare ayudarte!

Comment: @sioesi , ya lo  puse! la cosa es eso, que minimo uno, tendría que ser correcto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien amigo, viendo tu codepen me di cuenta que el error son los espacios en blanco.

Primero elimine todos los espacios generados aqui

```
squares[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+ R +", "+ G +", "+ B +")";
squareColor.push("rgb("+ R +", "+ G +", "+ B +")");
```

Segundo elimine los del `clickedColor`

```
clickedColor = clickedColor.replace(/ /g,'');
```

Tercero elimine los del `pickedColor`

```
pickedColor = pickedColor.replace(/ /g,'');
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! vaya fallo mas tonto!

Comment: a todos nos pasa! jaaja @Varox suerte!

Answer (score 1):

El problema ocurre cuando le asignas el backgroundColor al elemento con formato `rgb( r, g, b)` este se corrije quedando `rgb(r, g, b)`, remueve los espacios para que la comparacion sea verdadera.